# pom.xml file error due to dependencies and/or plugins

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, pom.xml

I seem to have a pom.xml file error with dependencies/plugins, I generated this pom.xml file by converting the project to Maven which then only generated this pom file. View the error codes below. The Java code itself does not contain errors according to Eclipse STS (Java Spring), all jar files required by imports in the java code have been imported.

**Console error print when running the Java program:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:190)
    at testingpushnotifications.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

**pom.xml file shows errors in a Java spring project.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring-Android-Push-Notifications-FCM--master</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring-Android-Push-Notifications-FCM--master</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>   <--- ERROR HERE
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

There's also a big red X on line 1.

**Error log from above code @line 16 :'plugin'**

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile 
     (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its 
     dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1: 
     ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from/to central 
     (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): NullPointerException
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile 
     (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
```

**Error of POM.XML file line 16**

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): NullPointerException    pom.xml /Spring-Android-Push-Notifications-FCM--master  line 16 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

**EDITED according to comment adding dependencies; result = remaining errors remain unresolved, no new errors.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring-Android-Push-Notifications-FCM--master</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring-Android-Push-Notifications-FCM--master</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version> 
</dependency>
        </configuration> 
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [3.5.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: sounds a bit like you can't access your maven repo. does `mvn -X help:help` tell you anything useful?

Answer (score 2):

You put in the wrong place for `<dependency>` tag, it's must be inside on `<dependencies>` tag and it's not inside `<build>` tag but it should be like this

```
....
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the jar for commons-logging just add the dependency in you pom.xml file  whatever version you are using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

Just try to add java version if you are using Java 8 and try to set the java path as well.

```
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
```

Comment: Managed to add both those codes without new errors, though they did not resolve the previous errors.

Comment: You have added the commons-logging dependency tag at wrong remove.Just take out that commons-logging dependency tag outside the <plugin> and all inside the <dependencies> tag

Comment: Thanks but I have dropped this method, i've continued with a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Some steps which may help:**

1. In some instance , you will start seeing error as we tried force update , saying , failure to transfer X dependency from Y path , resolutions will not be reattempted , bla bla bla
     **In such case quickly fix it by cd to .m2/repository folder and run following command :**

for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i

2. Rt click your project -> Maven -> Update project -> Select Force update -> Click OK
3. Under properties tag , add :

> ```
> >  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
> > <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> ```